# Scanning GS1 Databar Barcode in IOS with react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, barcode-scanner, gs1-databar

I want to scan GS1 Databar Barcode which is also known as RSS Expanded barcode  in IOS with react-native, I am using react-native-qrcode-scanner https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner to scan barcodes.

```
<QRCodeScanner
                onRead={this.onSuccess}
                showMarker={true}
                reactivate={false}
                flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.auto}
                topContent={
                    <View>
                        <Text>
                            Scan Coupon Barcode
                    </Text>
                        <Text>Please fit the barcode within the {'\n'} box on the screen.</Text>
                    </View>
                }
                cameraStyle={styles.cameraContainer}
                topViewStyle={styles.topcontainer}
                bottomViewStyle={styles.zeroContainer}
                markerStyle={styles.markerStyle}
                containerStyle={styles.container}
            />
```

It is working fine in android, but failing to pick barcodes in IOS. In IOS QR Code, EAN-8 barcodes are being scanned successfully, but GS1 Databar is not being scanned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No efficient open source solutions found for scanning GS1 Databar Expanded barcodes on iOS using React-Native.

Tried [Zxingify-ObjC](https://github.com/zxingify/zxingify-objc) as a native module but the scanning is poor on newer iPhones (11 Pro, 12).

Tried [react-native-barcode](https://github.com/yvvw/react-native-barcode) plugin. Doesn't support GS1 Databar plugin using the camera scanner, but does support scanning GS1 Databar from static images.

Finally went for a paid SDK: [Cognex](https://www.cognex.com/).

Hope this helps someone who runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

string.replace(/\D/g, "") apply this method on resulted string.